# How to avoid creating bean for ServiceImpl classes in Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-rest

I am developing the **Spring MVC + Spring Security + Spring Rest example using mongoDB**. In this example to, I see that I've more than 200 of classes (`Service and ServiceImpl`) and to create an instance of these classes in `Controller` classes, so for that I've to configure the bean in the `applicationContext.xml`.   Is there any way to have all those beans created automatically?

**application-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
             xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="locations">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>database.properties</beans:value>
             </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.XXXX.XXX.XXX.model"/>

    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="${mongo.db.host}" port="${mongo.db.port}"/>

    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.XXXX.XXXX.XXX.repositories"/>

    <beans:bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongo.db.name}"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="employeeService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.EmployeeServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="departmentService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.DepartmentServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="financeService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.FinanceServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="siteService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.SiteServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="helpService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.HelpServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="facilityService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.FacilityServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="conditionService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.ConditionServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="gameService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.GameServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="reportService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.ReportServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="roleService" class="com.XXX.XXX.services.RoleServiceImpl"/>
     ...........
     ...........
     ...........
     ...........
     <!-- So many service classes -->

</beans:beans>
```

Please let me know if you need any other details. I'm using XML based configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have enabled component-scan, you should be able mark the classes with stereo type markers so that there automatically picked up. So  no need to define them in your xml

ex.

- Services -> @Service
- Controllers -> @Controller
- Components or other beans -> @Component

Comment: If I dont define those beans, then @Autowirning will not worked at all in Controller classes of ServiceImpl bean

Comment: if you have included your component scan to include service and other classes @autowire should work just fine